# Page redirecting not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

Hi I am trying to redirect to a new controller once an account has been created, but for some reason the code does not work.  Here is my code:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Register(Register model)
{
    if(ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        try
        {
            Membership.CreateUser(model.Username, model.Password, model.EMail);
            Roles.AddUserToRole(model.Username, "subscriber");
            RedirectToAction("AccountCreated" , "Account");
        } 
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("" , ex.Message);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError("" , "One or more fields are not completed");
    }
    return View(model);
}

public ActionResult AccountCreated()
{
    return View();
}
```

I have tried both `RedirectToAction("AccountCreated" , "Account");` and `Redirect("~/Account/AccountCreated")` but both don't work.  While debugging I noticed that when it reaches that portion of the code, it skips it.

And I know the application does not throw an exception because it creates the account.

What is the problem here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to return an `ActionResult` from your Action, so change the line to

```
return RedirectToAction("AccountCreated" , "Account");
```

See MSDN example of [Controller.RedirectToAction](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd470594%28v=vs.98%29.aspx).